# How can I use from Structuremap auto register in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

I have a simple mvc application that has 3 layer

1. Ui => has refrence to Common And Services
2. Common
3. Services => has refrence to Common

I define my Service Contracts in  Common layer and implement it in services layer

```
//Common layer
public interface IPersonService
{
  void Foo();
}
//Services layer
public classPersonService:IPersonService
{
  void Foo()
  {
    //To DO
  }
}
```

In my Global.asax I write this code for initial Structuremap container

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        }
```

Now,in my controller when I want get instance from IPersonService like this

```
var personService= ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPersonService>();
```

I get this error

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type '*.IPersonService'

Is there any idea for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify other assemblies to scan using the `AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory()` function, like so:

```
scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("YourNamespace.Common"));
scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("YourNamespace.Services"));
```

Seeing as you tagged this question as a StructureMap 3 question, I would advise against using the `ObjectFactory` as Jeremy Miller (the author of StructureMap) has made it clear that it [will be removed in future version](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0). In fact, you should get a warning that it will be removed in a future version.

Instead you should aim to configure your container like so:

```
IContainer container = new Container();
container.Configure(c => {
    c.IncludeRegistry<YourRegistry>();
});

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

You can read more about StructureMap's registries [here](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/).